# JQuery Autocomplete Array of Objects from String

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

In order to satisfy a JQuery autocomplete I have, right now, used this initialization code:

```
var KdNameTags = [{label:"...", idx:0},{label:"...", idx:1},{...}]
```

This works well, and it initializes an array of objects, each one containing a property "label" and "idx", like demanded by autocomplete. See details in the JQuery docs if required. Now, I want the definition delivered via a string variable, like:

```
var strTags = '{label:"...", idx:0},{label:"...", idx:1},{...}';
```

but I can't figure out how I need to proceed, and I have Javascript creating the array of objects from that string.

```
var KdNameTags = [strTags]
```

it does not do the trick, of course...

Comment: Your string not in proper json format, so you won't be able to parse it using JSON.parse().... will you be able to fix the code that is generating the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var strTags = '{"label":"...", "idx":0},{"label":"...", "idx":1}';
var arr = JSON.parse("[" + strTags + "]");
console.log(arr);
$("pre").text(JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm. First hint was to bring the init string into JSON format (put "" around the member names), and then shove the string into a JSON parser, I prefer to use

`jQuery.parseJSON(strTags);`

but your code has showed me the way. Excellent!

Answer (score 2):

You can add `"[]"` to the string variable and then use **[eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)**, to create your array of objects.

```
var strTags = '[{label:"...", idx:0},{label:"...", idx:1}]';
var yourObject = eval(strTags)
```

Comment: It's really nice method, +1 added

Comment: Would have worked too, I guess, but I preferred to go the JSON parser idea. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this , with the help of replace() and JSON.parse()

```js
var strTags = '{label:"...", idx:0},{label:"...", idx:1}';

var json = JSON.parse('[' + strTags.replace(/({|,)\s*(\w+)\s*:/g, '$1"$2":') + ']');

console.log(json);
```